# Comparing two dates(string) in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, date, google-sheets

I am trying to compare 2 dates in Google App Scripts using JavaScript. The problem i am having is the result is not right and i followed mulitple suggestions on Stackoverflow but it did not work.

**This is my code:**
 - This is the code for getting a Date from today - 30days

```
  var date = new Date();
  var last_30 = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);
  var delete_date = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'Etc/GMT', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

**This is my code:**
 - This is the code from getting Values from a spreadsheet that is in dateformat

```
    var row = values[i];  // Values from Spreadsheet cells    
    var dt = new Date(row[0]);
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1 ;
    var day = dt.getDate();      
    var cell_date_value = ('0' + dt.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/'
             + ('0' + (dt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '/'
             + dt.getFullYear();

    Logger.log('cell:'+cell_date_value + ' delete:'+delete_date);

    if (Date.parse(cell_date_value) > Date.parse(delete_date)) {  
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
```

**This is my Logger.log():**

```
[19-05-06 15:19:40:579 CEST] cell_value:03/05/2019  delete_before:06/04/2019
[19-05-06 15:19:40:580 CEST] cell_value:03/05/2019  delete_before:06/04/2019
[19-05-06 15:19:40:581 CEST] cell_value:03/05/2019  delete_before:06/04/2019
[19-05-06 15:19:40:581 CEST] cell_value:03/04/2019  delete_before:06/04/2019
[19-05-06 15:19:40:582 CEST] cell_value:03/03/2019  delete_before:06/04/2019
[19-05-06 15:19:40:583 CEST] cell_value:03/03/2019  delete_before:06/04/2019
[19-05-06 15:19:40:584 CEST] cell_value:03/02/2019  delete_before:06/04/2019
```

As you can see the `cell_value` is more than `delete_before` old on the 4 last rows but still this cell are not picked up under the if statement. The `typeOf` is `string`

***I also tried this: (did not work):***

```
var d1 = Date.parse(cell_value);
var d2 = Date.parse(delete_before);
if (d1 < d2) {
    alert ("Error!");
}
```

And this:

```
function isLater(str1, str2)
{
    return new Date(str1) > new Date(str2);
}
```

Anyone can see the problem?

Comment: Why do you format `delete_date` as a string when you're just going to turn it back into a Date instance again?

Comment: Just do `dt > new Date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try to compare timestamps instead of time objects

```
var d1 = Date.parse(cell_value).getTime();
var d2 = Date.parse(delete_before).getTime();
if (d1 < d2) {
    alert ("Error!");
}
```

getTime() returns milliseconds spend sinse 1970, so you can compare 2 integers easy.

As example:

```
Date.parse(cell_value) != Date.parse(cell_value)
```

you are comparing 2 object instances. So basicly you are asking is this the same object. Not is this the same time.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. But why did my code over not work?, what is the reason for .getTime() should work

Comment: @AliDurrani You may have been comparing the objects themselves which were being compared by some arbitrary rules (I'm not sure what rules comparing JS maps follows), when you wanted to compare the times they represent.

Comment: @AliDurrani I have extended the answer

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks for clarifying! Understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();
if(date1.getTime()>date.getTime())
{ 
  console.log("Date1 is greater")
}
else{
 console.log("Date2 is greater");
```

}

Date method "**getTime()**" gives time in milliseconds which can be used for comparison

Comment: use parse method for parsing date as shown in above answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
function date_splitter(date){
   var parts = date.split("/");
   return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
}
if (date_splitter(cell_date_value) < date_splitter(delete_date)) {  
  sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
  rowsDeleted++;
}
```

This worked!

Comment: probably not correct... even date parsing looks wrong for me